# my code is show to me just first result and bring the other null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have a problem...

I have a table which name is event attends and we record them to the tables with ID. the ID of the event and the user ID.

when I want to list the the event attends I need to bring the users from users table and bring the name and the phone and the e-mail.

but when I write the code the ID is result true. but when I put the second SQL inside the loop the code bring to me just the first record and bring the other null.

can any body help me...

I'm beginner at PHP so i have mistakes :(

```
// START TABLE CONNECTIONS //
$result_event_attends = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event_attends where course_id='" .$val_selected_event_id. "'  ORDER BY idcourse_attends DESC");
$total_results_event_attends = mysql_num_rows($result_event_attends);
$total_pages_event_attends = ceil($total_results_event_attends / $per_page);
// END TABLE CONNECTIONS //


// PAGINATION START //
// check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];

    // make sure the $show_page value is valid
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
    {
        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page; 
    }
    else
    {
        // error - show first set of results
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page; 
    }       
}
else
{
    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page; 
}

// PAGINATION END //

// START TO GET RESUTLS //

// CHECK IF THE RESULTS 0 AND GIVE ERROR //

$num_rows_event_attends = mysql_num_rows($result_event_attends);

if($num_rows_event_attends == 0)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>";
        echo "<center><strong>Oh snap!</strong> There are no records. Do you want add records?</center>";
        echo "</div>";  
    }

// END CHECK IF THE RESULTS 0 AND GIVE ERROR //

else {
    echo "<BR><table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Attender Name</center></td>';
    echo '<th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Registration No</center></td>';
    echo '<th colspan="4"><center>Actions</center></td>';
    echo "</tr>";   

    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {   
        // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
        $user_id = mysql_result($result_event_attends, $i, 'user_id');
        $user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where userID='" .$user_id. "'");
        $total_results_user_info = mysql_num_rows($user_info);      

        if ($i == $total_results_event_attends) { break; }      

        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td style="vertical-align:middle">' . mysql_result($user_info, $i, 'name') . '</td>';
        echo '<td style="vertical-align:middle">' . mysql_result($result_event_attends, $i, 'company_id') . '</td>';
        echo '<td width="40px"><center><a href="events.php?action=delete_conf&id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'EV_ID') . '" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Attendes List"><i class="icon-group"></i></a></center></td>';
        echo '<td width="40px"><center><a href="events.php?action=delete_conf&id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'EV_ID') . '" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Delete"><i class="icon-trash-o"></i></a></center></td>';
        echo '<td width="40px"><center><a href="events.php?action=edit&id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'EV_ID') . '" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></center></td>';
        echo '<td width="40px"><center><a href="events.php?action=details&id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'EV_ID') . '" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Details"><i class="icon-bars"></i></a></center></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }       

    // close table>
    echo "</table>"; 

    // display pagination
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<div class='pagination pagination-centered'>";
    echo "<ul> ";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
    {
        echo "<li><a href='?page=$i'>$i</a></li> ";
    }
    echo "</ul> ";
    echo "</div> ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the queries, you would be much better off learning to use your database efficiently from the start. What you have is a loop of queries that isn't efficient at all.

This is what you have now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_attends 
where course_id='$val_selected_event_id'  
ORDER BY idcourse_attends DESC
;
/* inefficiently this is repeated for each row from the first query */
SELECT * 
FROM users 
where userID = '$user_id'
;
```

You could achieve the same result with this **single query**:

```
SELECT ca.* , u.*
FROM event_attends ca
INNER JOIN users u ON ca.user_id = u.user_id
where ca.course_id='$val_selected_event_id'  
ORDER BY ca.idcourse_attends DESC
```

Be careful with `select *`; it should not be used in production code. You should list out the fields you actually need, this way you minimize the job of gathering and transporting data to your app.

Also note the use of `ca` and `u` which are `table aliases` prefix each field you reference with this so the dbms will know which field is being referenced.

Comment: @Abdulrahman El-Halab ; just realized I had missed the join condition (pretty important!) **ON ca.user_id = u.user_id**

Answer (score 1):

To preface this, I highly recommend using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as opposed to the `mysql` functions you're currently using.

You seem to be doing things somewhat inefficiently, as you're querying your database on each iteration of a loop.  Consider taking all of your database results and converting them into a multidimensional array (`mysqli_fetch_all` would be a good start if you decide to use `mysqli`) and then looping through the first dimension of that array and performing any validation then.

Also, you might consider using a SQL join to consolidate your data.  Your code is a little unclear, so I'm not entirely sure either of these options are valid (also why I'm hesitant to provide examples).

Comment: PHP's MySQL api is deprecated, so adopting MySQLi or PDO  is good practice